# Mysql Trigger - Update status_id if the value exist in other Table

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

Currently, I have two Tables:

`ocok_country`

| status | country_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |

** country_id 3 and 4 not updated with the trigger **

`ocok_zone_to_geo_zone`

| name | country_id |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| DEF | 2 |
| new-country-zone | 3 |
| new-country-zone | 4 |

I have created a query that will Update the table `ocok_county.status` to `1` IF the `ocok_zone_to_geo_zone.country_id` Exist - see Country_id 1 and 2 on the tables

```
UPDATE ocok_country c
SET c.status = CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ocok_zone_to_geo_zone s
            WHERE s.country_id = c.country_id
        ) THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END;
```

Now, I have also tried to create a trigger that will do this and save me some time but, I cannot find where is the error and I'll appreciate your help on this one
Thanks!
See country_id 3 and 4 not updated in status

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_ocok_zone_trigger AFTER UPDATE
ON
    `ocok_country` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `ocok_zone_to_geo_zone`
        WHERE
            `country_id` = NEW.country_id
    ) THEN
UPDATE
    `ocok_country`
SET
    `status` = '1'
WHERE
    `country_id` = NEW.country_id;
END IF;
END;
```

Currently using `mysql 8.0.32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER INSERT ON ocok_zone_to_geo_zone
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE ocok_country
    SET status = 1
    WHERE country_id = NEW.country_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, I also forgot to ask, what if I remove a country row from the table `ocok_zone_to_geo_zone`, now that such country_id doesn't exist in the table, this should disable the `ocok_country.status = 0` in a way to make it dynamic and not create multiple triggers

Comment: @carloslozada *what if I remove a country row from the table ocok_zone_to_geo_zone* Of course you must create according AFTER UPDATE and AFTER DELETE triggers.